# Unexpected errors, not sure why

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initializer

I can not seem to get my code to run properly. I get the error message

"Error  1   error C2078: too many initializers, Line: 17    Column: 1"

and

"Error  2   IntelliSense: expected a ')'    Line: 17    Comlumn: 21"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getScore(int &, int &, int &, int &,int &);
void calcAverage(int, int, int, int, int);
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
    string response; 


    getScore(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    int findlowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    //calcAverage(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);

    cout << "Are there any more test scores?" << endl;
    cin >> response;
    cout << endl;
    if (response == "yes")
    {
        getScore(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
        //calcAverage(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void getScore(int &num1, int &num2, int &num3, int &num4, int &num5)
{
    cout << "What was your score for the first test?" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << endl;
    if (num1 < 1 || num1 > 100)
    {
        cout<<"Scores must be between 1 and 100, re-enter the score" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
    }

    cout << "What was your score for the second test?" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl;
    if(num2 < 1 || num2 > 100)
    {
        cout<<"Scores must be between 1 and 100, re-enter the score" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
    }

    cout << "What was your score for the third test?" << endl;
    cin >> num3;
    cout << endl;
    if(num3 < 1 || num3 > 100)
    {
        cout<<"Scores must be between 1 and 100, re-enter the score" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
    }

    cout << "What was your score for the fourth test?" << endl;
    cin >> num4;
    cout << endl;
    if(num4 < 1 || num4 > 100)
    {
        cout<<"Scores must be between 1 and 100, re-enter the score" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
    }

    cout << "What was your score for the fifth test?" << endl;
    cin >> num5;
    cout << endl;
    if(num5 < 1 || num5 > 100)
    {
        cout<<"Scores must be between 1 and 100, re-enter the score" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
    }
}
int findLowest(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4, int num5)
{
    int lowest;
    lowest = num1;

    if (num2 < lowest)
    {
        lowest = num2;
    }
    else if (num3 < lowest)
    {
        lowest = num3;
    }
    else if (num4 < lowest)
    {
        lowest = num4;
    }
    else if (num5 < lowest)
    {
        lowest = num5;
    }
    cout << "the lowest test score is " << lowest << endl;

    return lowest;
}
void calcAverage(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4, int num5)
{
    int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);
    int lowest;
    double average;

    findLowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);

    cout << lowest << endl;
    average = (((float)num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) - lowest) / 4.0;
    cout << showpoint << setprecision(8) << average << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cnange this statement

```
   int findlowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
```

to

```
   int lowest = findLowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
```

or simply as

```
   findLowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
```

because you do not use the return value.

Also the name of the function is `findLowest`.

Also this part of the code

```
cout << "Are there any more test scores?" << endl;
cin >> response;
cout << endl;
if (response == "yes")
{
    getScore(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    //calcAverage(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
}
```

has no any sense.

Function findLowest is also wrong. It does not find the lowest. For example consider the case when num1, num2, num3, num4, num5 have balues 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 correspondingly.

And even function calcAverage is wrong because it uses uninintialized variable lowest.

There should be

```
int lowest = findLowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
```

However due to the bad design of function findLowest the message about the lowest number will be outputed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Also notice you define the function as
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);
with a "L"
and you call it with
int findlowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
with a "l"
not the same function name :).